# How does metallicity affect stellar evolution?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, stellar-evolution, metallicity

The main sequence evolution of a solitary star depends most of all on its initial mass. Other factors influencing its evolution are the initial metallicity, rotation and magnetism.

Question: how does the initial sun-like metallicity affect the evolution while the star is on the main sequence,

(i) in a star of $1M_\odot$ initial mass

(ii) in a star of $>5M_\odot$ initial mass?

(a) I guess the three pp-chains in the sun and the heavy star aren't affected directly by $Z$.

(b) The CNO-cycles do not contribute more than 1-2 % to the energy production at the core temperature of the sun. This will not be more at higher $Z$, I presume. They contribute much more in a heavy star with solar $Z$ and even more if $Z$ is higher than solar, I think.

(c) Metallicity may influence the opacity and radiative transport in the interior and atmosphere of both stars, but I don't know how. Indirectly, this could influence (a) and (b), e.g. through temperature dependence of fusion reactions.

(d) ...?

I've seen a few Q&A's in Stackexchange about calculating and modeling the influence of metallicity, but I would like to have a qualitative answer (physical mechanisms).